Spending paths for subset of n-of-n multisig
I would like to achieve the following.
A group of N people come together and create an n-of-n multisig. Each of them funds this multisig with a custom amount of bitcoin. At some point in the future, they decide to spend these funds, however a subset K of the initial group has disappeared or is not reacting anymore.
Is it possible to achieve the following behavior:

The K people who are not reacting are getting their initially contributed funds back
The remaining (N - K) people, who are available to sign, agree together where the remaining funds are sent to. Basically as if the multisig had been an (N-K)-of-(N-K) to begin with.

I thought one possible way (please correct me if I am wrong) would be to use some taproot functionality and include various spending paths in the merkle tree that allow all possible subsets of users to spend as described above. This would be achieved by presigning a bunch of transactions upon the creation of the multisig that use these different spending paths. These transactions are signed in a way that outputs returned to the non-reactive users are defined ahead of time and for the rest of the funds, the remaining users need to decide and agree unanimously where they want to send them to when the time for it has come.
Would this work? Even if the answer is yes, with a growing number of users N, the combinations of subsets explodes which makes this infeasible, so maybe there is a better way.
Thank you very much for your feedback!
